# Internal Server Error (500) Asp.Net Boilerplate Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have downloaded the free *Asp.Net Boilerplate* template for Angualr + Asp.Net Core, have created a new entity for Company and respected Dto(s) for it.

For accessing the API, I tried to create a dynamic controller by creating *ICompanyAppService* with the implementation *CompanyAppService*.

But it's showing the internal server error (500) while accessing this link "`/api/services/app/Company/GetAll`".

Swagger UI is showing the correct proper API URl(s) as User's. Please try to help me on this issue.

Here is the link for the solution: https://github.com/rsoni20/AspNetBoilerPlate

and link for Logs.txt -
https://github.com/rsoni20/AspNetBoilerPlate/blob/master/Logs.txt

Comment: Make sure your Content-Type: application/json

Comment: yes it's application/json.

Comment: I see in the logs - ME.Companies.CompanyAppService.
Could not find a parameterless constructor. So as the log say, you should check this class, and add parameterless constructor

Comment: Yes,  I changed from protected to public and now it's working. Thanks @ZivWeissman

Comment: i downloaded your project. and it seems to working on startup. there's no ui. so i couldn't test. (swagger ui requests doesn't work because of bearer token auth that's why i couldn't test that way as well.)

Comment: Np, i'll add it as an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is with the class *ME.Companies.CompanyAppService*

It must have a public parameter-less constructor, and it had a private one.

Comment: no such a requirement. Dependency system will inject all parameters.

Comment: Making the constructor public is enough.